# Getting ReferenceError: (token) is not defined JavaScript Discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Recently, I've been working on a bot called Music Bot. And, it showed up with this error message:

```
    C:\Users\yuhao\Desktop\discord-bot-master\index.js:51
client.login(token);
             ^

ReferenceError: token is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yuhao\Desktop\discord-bot-master\index.js:51:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

C:\Users\yuhao\Desktop\discord-bot-master>
```

My token format have lots of dots, but, at ReferenceError, it showed up with no dots and the one before the dot.

This the the script for index.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('./client/Client');
const {
    prefix,
    token,
} = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const queue = new Map();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

console.log(client.commands);

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
    console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    try {
        command.execute(message);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

And this is config.json:

```
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "token"
}
```

Thats all. Help me please on reply section, thx!

Comment: For the future, Java and JavaScript are two completely separate things. Please don't use the Java tag if you mean JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you haven't populated your token or prefix. You need to parse your JSON like this for the object in question to be populated.

JS:

```
const fs = require('fs')
...
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, "UTF-8");
client.login(config.token);
```

TS (with a class so you don't have to worry about mistyping values, as you will get autocompletion):

```
export default class Settings {
    public token: String;
    public prefix: String;
}
...
const config: Settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, "UTF-8");
client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('./client/Client');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const queue = new Map();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

console.log(client.commands);

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
    console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

    try {
        command.execute(message);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Please, don't just dump code, describe what you changed and why.

Comment: Hi, client.login(config.token);, need the config. ?

Comment: Its the right way to import json file to project. You cant import property by name, so you import  config file as `config` and then use his propertys like `config.property`